# Microsoft Word AddIn DocumentBeforeSave application event fire twice

Tags: c#, ms-word, event-handling

I working on this Microsoft Application Add-In for Word. I have BeforeSaveDocument event which fires twice. Is there a way to only catch the event once?

This is the AddIn_startup.

```
((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)app).DocumentBeforeSave += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(App_BeforeSaveDocument);
```

This is BeforeSaveDocument event handler, I have 2 other methods to extract paragragraphs from Word and then send a socket message. This method fires twice when Word Save event happens,

```
void App_BeforeSaveDocument(Word.Document document, ref bool saveAsUI, ref bool cancel)
    {
        extractParagraphInfo();
        handleMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at this in my own code to see whether the event fires twice and it does not appear to. You probably need to pin down where the event is firing again.
In the meanwhile you could set a flag in the event method to stop it doing this twice.

```
private bool beforeSave = false;

void App_BeforeSaveDocument(Word.Document document, ref bool saveAsUI, ref bool cancel)
{
    if(!beforeSave)
    {
        beforeSave = true;
        extractParagraphInfo();
        handleMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        beforeSave = false;
    }
}
```

Of course this will only work if it does fire twice and you can set it back again. Your best course of action is to work out why it's firing twice and fix it at source.